# Deleting an active record entry from a joined table without deleting the orginal

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I am working on a web application written in ruby on rails

There is a model of courses that exists in the database. 
A user has the ability to save courses that he/she plans to take.
I accomplish this by having a current_user.courses table.  (courses_users)

However, if a user wishes to remove a saved course, and I issue a delete request with that id like so

```
current_user.courses.find_by(id: params[:id]).destroy
```

I end up deleting both the entry in the joined table and the entry in the courses table. I confirmed this by looking at the server logs and found

```
DELETE FROM `courses_users` WHERE `courses_users`.`course_id` = 219
SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM `courses` WHERE `courses`.`id` = 219
```

Doing the two actions described above when I only want the first.

Is there a way to just remove just the entry in the joined table? Or does that go against the nature of a joined table? If so, is there a more efficient way of achieving this functionality?

Any help would be appreciated and if you would have me post anything else please ask.

Thank you,

EDIT: The relationships between the two models:

a user has_and_belongs_to_many courses

and a course has_and_belongs_to_many users

Comment: Please show the relationships between your models :)

Comment: Opinion: I dislike has_and_belongs_to_many for just this kind of situation. That is usually (but not always) masking another model. Perhaps a User has_many Enrollments, and has_many Courses through Enrollments. Course has_many Enrollments, and has_many Users through Enrollments, and an Enrollment belongs_to Course, and belongs_to User. The explicit Enrollment model lets you store additional attributes (perhaps the users Grade, or Credits, date enrolled, date dropped, or whatever).

Comment: @railsdog That's a very good point. At the present time I don't have a need for storing these other attributes, but it may be more beneficial in the long run. I'll look into revising my relationships. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is saying to destroy the course, so that's what ActiveRecord is doing.

You want to delete the association, not destroy the user nor the course.

The solution is to use `collection.delete(object, …)`

- This removes each object from the collection by deleting the association from the join table.
- This does not destroy the objects.

Example code:

```
def delete_user_course_association(user_id, course_id)
  user = User.find(user_id)
  course = user.courses.find(course_id)
  user.courses.delete(course) if course 
end
```

See [Rails API ActiveRecord Associations has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many)

Comment: Oh I see! I wasn't aware of the discrepancy. Thank you for the answer and helpful resource!

Answer (score 2):

The line below deletes the courses record with id `params[:id]`

```
current_user.courses.find_by(id: params[:id]).destroy
```

I think you meant to do:

```
  current_user.courses.delete( params[:id] )
```